# MySQL SELECT or SUBSELECT with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

i have a little problem with a query which i don't remember how to manage.
This is my db structure on phpmyadmin:

table user

```
hid(PK)
```

table request

```
id (PK), hid, word, time
```

table click

```
id, rid (FK)
```

the question is that I need to get the number of requests and the number of clicks for each word, with a given `hid` and between two dates, and I don't remember how to do it.

I've tried selecting all words and then do a query in a while loop to select the number of requests and clicks, but it always exceed the 30 seconds timeout.

This is what I've done, obviously with no results:

```
$q1="SELECT kwd,id FROM requests 
WHERE hid='$hid' 
AND time BETWEEN '$date1 $hour1:00:00' AND '$date2 $hour2:00:00'
LIMIT $limit,50";
$qr1=mysql_query($q1) or die (mysql_error());
while(($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($qr1))!=null)
{
    $k=$r['kwd'];
    $q2="SELECT * FROM requests 
    WHERE hid='$hid' 
    AND time BETWEEN '$date1 $hour1:00:00' AND '$date2 $hour2:00:00' 
    AND kwd='$k'
    LIMIT $limit,50";
    $qr2=mysql_query($q2) or die (mysql_error())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html), and [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
$q1="SELECT r.kwd, COUNT(c.id) as NumberOfClicks FROM click c
INNER JOIN requests r ON r.id = c.rid
WHERE r.hid='$hid' 
AND r.time BETWEEN '$date1 $hour1:00:00' AND '$date2 $hour2:00:00'
GROUP BY r.kwd
LIMIT $limit,50";

$qr1=mysql_query($q1) or die (mysql_error());

while(($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($qr1))!=null)
{
    $k=$r['kwd'];
    $c=$r['NumberOfClicks'];
}
```

In the above code, `$k` would be the word and `$c` would be the number of clicks for the related word.

**UPDATE**

If you also want to get the number of requests for each word, use `RIGHT JOIN` since there could be requests that don't have any related clicks.

```
$q1="SELECT r.kwd, 
    COUNT(c.id) AS NumberOfClicks, 
    COUNT(r.kwd) AS NumberOfRequests
FROM click c
RIGHT JOIN requests r ON r.id = c.rid
WHERE r.hid='$hid' 
AND r.time BETWEEN '$date1 $hour1:00:00' AND '$date2 $hour2:00:00'
GROUP BY r.kwd
LIMIT $limit,50";

$qr1=mysql_query($q1) or die (mysql_error());

while(($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($qr1))!=null)
{
    $k=$r['kwd'];
    $c=$r['NumberOfClicks'];
    $requests=$r['NumberOfRequests'];
}
```

`$k` would be the word, `$c` would be the number of clicks, and `$requests` would be the number of requests for the related word.

Comment: Really, thank you so much, I didn't remember this method, maybe too much time without writing queries :)

Comment: What if I would like to show also the number of requests related to that word?

Comment: Sorry, I was saying, for each word, the number of requests and the number of clicks, I was not enough clear :)

Comment: Sorry, I think i need another help, sorry for annoying you, but, could you please explain me how to do this:

on the same db tables as reported first, for each request, i should get the average time between the request and its related click...
i've tried this but i'm not sure if it's working properly:



    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,r.time,c.time)
    FROM requests r RIGHT JOIN clicks c
    ON r.id=c.rid
    WHERE r.hid='$hid'

Comment: Please ask a new question, your new problem is out of context of this question.